# ActiveMQ, SSL, and transport connectors

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, https, activemq-classic

Using this site as a guide:

http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl.html

I performed the following (I added a little to the keytool commands found within th esite)

```
keytool -genkey -alias broker -keyalg RSA -keystore /home/amq/broker.ks -dname "CN=server, O=IBM, C=GB" -keypass passw0rd -storepass passw0rd

keytool -export -alias broker -keystore /home/amq/broker.ks -file /home/amq/broker_cert -storepass passw0rd

keytool -genkey -alias client -keyalg RSA -keystore /home/client/client.ks -dname "CN=client, O=IBM, C=GB" -keypass passw0rd -storepass passw0rd

keytool -import -alias broker -keystore /home/client/client.ts -file /home/amq/broker_cert -storepass passw0rd

keytool -export -alias client -keystore /home/client/client.ks -file /home/client/client_cert -storepass passw0rd

keytool -import -alias client -keystore /home/amq/broker.ts -file /home/client/client_cert -storepass passw0rd
```

Now the keystore and trust store are created, I started the broker

```
export SSL_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/home/amq/broker.ks\ -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=passw0rd\ -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/home/amq/broker.ts

cd /usr/local/activemq/apache-activemq-5.9.0
bin/activemq console
```

So far, all is good, and what I want to do is take the ProducerTool.java that ships with the installation, and run it agaisnt the SSL

I am somewhat mystified by the documentation, as follows

> Using Spring to configure SSL for a Broker instance
>
> Sometimes the use of javax.net.ssl.* system properties is not
>   appropriate as they effect all SSL users in a JVM. ActiveMQ 5.2.x adds
>   an  element to the  that allows a broker
>   specific set of SSL properties to be configured.
>
> The SslContext test case validates starting an SSL transport listener
>   using the configuration specified in the broker Xbean. The SslContext
>   element is added to the broker as follows:
>
> ```
> <amq:sslContext>
>   <amq:sslContext
>         keyStore="server.keystore" keyStorePassword="password"
>         trustStore="client.keystore" trustStorePassword="password"/>
> </amq:sslContext>
>
> <amq:transportConnectors>
>   <amq:transportConnector uri="ssl://localhost:61616" />
> </amq:transportConnectors>
> </amq:broker> </beans>
> ```
>
> The SslContext is used to configure the SslTransportFactory for that
>   broker. Full details of the configuration options available can be
>   seen in the schema definition or in the accessors of
>   org.apache.activemq.spring.SpringSslContext

What I gather from this is that since I do not care that all JVM users will be forced to use SSL, I am good, and do not need any Spring configurations.  (At least I hope so)

I am bothered by 2 thingss

1> Am I correct in believing that I do not need to perform any Spring configuration, and I can simply use the -Djava options

2> Nor do I think I need the ssl transport connector, that I should just be able to run the ProducerTool.java code and be good to go.  Why do I think this, because if I need to add the SSL transport connector to the borker that is extra config, and it is forcing a change to the source code.

Am I correct in assuming

1> I do not need any Spring changes since I want all JVM users to go with SSL

2> Can I not use the ssl transport connector, and simply use the ProducerTool.java, essentially making the default connection use SSL ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is a JMS client, so either way (eith the SSL transport, or without), the client will connect to port 61616, since the SSL transport is configured as 61616

But I can not tell from the documentation whether the transport is a requirement or not

Any ideas